# How to add second icon to google chrome extention with a different action on click?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need two icons with different actions (first will open popup window, second will just run js script) in one extension. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this manifest file specs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest

As the keys impliy, you can have only one browser_action (single noun) OR one page_action (also single noun) for you extension.

How about putting you buttons in the popup?

Comment: Thank you for answer, it's regard optimization, because one click is better then two clicks)